# How do I run a multivariate multiple regression in R with two sets of my independent variable?

Tags: r

I have two dependent variables (the metabolic rates of two different crab species) that are linked to an independent variable (temperature). I want to know if the rates for the two species have a statistically significant difference against temperature. I intend to use `manova()` to accomplish this, however my temperature data isn't a single vector which both my metabolic rate vectors are linked to. Rather, I have two different temperature data that occupy similar ranges, one for each species. What code should I use?

The code I would use if I only had one set of temperature data is

```
test <- manova(cbind(rock, shore) ~ temperature, data = class_data)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you trying to do MANOVA. To me it doesn't look like you have a multivariate setup. You should probably use a model like `test <- aov(metabolic_rate ~ temperature * species, data = DF)`, where `DF` is the result of reshaping your data to long format.

Comment: @Roland Yeah I knew using `manova()` wouldn't make sense for this context but I wans't sure what function to use (I'm pretty new to statistics and R). What results would `aov()` give me?
As for syntax, what does `* species` mean? What would my data frame need to look like for this to work?

Comment: See if [this site](https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-multivariate-multiple-regression/) helps.

Comment: @Kat that site only talks about when you have one set of independent data, but I have two.

Comment: Forget about "sets of independent data". You have have one dependent variable, one continuous independent variable and a grouping variable (categorical independent variable). You want to have both independent variables as main (fixed) effects and you generally want the interaction between them. The code in my comment will include all of that and do an ANOVA.